# Allow user to reorder GTK list

Tags: list, gtk, gtk2

I have a list of items, either in styled text format or in columned form, that I would like the user to be able to reorder themselves.
(and I'm not talking about merely sorting by a column, either)

Is there a widget that supports this, or at least a commonly-used setup?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [GtkTreeView](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/TreeWidgetObjects.html) widget for this. The elements inside this widget can be reordered at will, you could for example provide buttons next to the list to provide the possibility to move around elements, or even allow for drag and drop, which can take some effort to implement though (EDIT: at least for the case you need to set rules for the reordering). It's possible to set different background and foreground colors for each cell, and even images and check boxes can be packed into cells. GtkTreeView can be used with simple lists (GtkListStore used for data storage) or for tree-like data structures (GtkTreeStore).

There are some tutorials out there, one I found quite useful to start with is [this one.](http://scentric.net/tutorial/treeview-tutorial.html) It also has many examples and is in fact linked to from the official GTK+ site. You might also want to take a closer look at GtkTreeSortable, for which you can define your own sorting functions.

This topic is also extensively covered inside Andrew Krause's book [Foundations of GTK+ Development](http://www.gtkbook.com/). It is a bit dated now (covers GTK 2), but there haven't been many changes for the GtkTreeView widget inside GTK so far, so the content still applies.

Comment: To rearrange a treeview using drag and drop just call [gtk_tree_view_set_reorderable()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-set-reorderable)

Comment: If the reordering can be done arbitrary then OK - I'll edit my post to make that clear.